# C# WFA VSTUDIO2012 Looking for something like "if combobox & textbox then"

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, combobox, textbox

I been using c# for only a few months, I've made a few small programs but now I want to do something a bit bigger, problem is I haven't actually done any kind of course/training, just picked up bits here and there and got by.
I have made many searches on this site and others, google and bing etc
but they all point me to something different (or so I believe) so here's my question

I have on my Windows Form Aplication
 1 combobox with 3 entries
 1 textbox
and 2 labels (which could have been textboxes but I like the look better on my WFA)

what i'm looking for in the running application is, I want to select one of the combobox options then in the text box type in a value
e.g combobox to "optionA" textbox to "40" then change the labels to a predetermined text.
so if combobox = optionA and also textbox = 40 the change labels else labels are clear.

I tried

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "optionA") && (textBox1.Text = "40")
            {
                label3.Text = "40A";
                label4.Text = "A40";
            }
```

But I get all kinds of errors.
Any help would be much appreciated, I will take lessons one day I promise
If you need more information, please ask and I shall try to deliver.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "I get all kinds of errors" is not a problem description. You know what the errors are;  they're right in front of you. There is absolutely no reason to fail to provide them so we can see them as well. If you want help, **be specific** when you ask your questions.

Comment: Sorry Ken, I'm still at work and also at time of writing my question and I don't have my personal laptop with me, so I wrote what I had from memory, unfortunately I couldn't remember the issues. next time I will provide as much info as possible. I will try some of the suggestions given below. Thank you for your communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your `if` statement:

1. The entire condition expression must be enclosed in brackets.
2. You are assigning the value "40" to `textBox1.Text`, not comparing the contents.

Your could should work like this:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "optionA" && textBox1.Text == "40")
{
    label3.Text = "40A";
    label4.Text = "A40";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct syntax for C#. The if statement as you wrote it only applies to the first half of the expression - leaving the second half to confuse the compiler, as it's not part of anything that would be expecting a true/false value. You need an additional set of parentheses surrounding the entire expression, so both parts are interpreted as being part of the if statement. You also need to use double-equals in the expression after the 'and' - with the single-equals it means "set textBox1.Text to 40", which will always be true (and have an undesired side effect). Like this:

```
if ((comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "optionA") && (textBox1.Text == "40"))
{
    [your code you want to be conditionally run]
}
```